# Invalid signature error in Amazon AWS API "itemsearch" call using ColdFusion

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, coldfusion, aws-sdk

I am stuck on a error that is the invalid signature. I am calling the itemsearch API, but before that my signature (version 4) is not working.

This is the cfc file "amazonsig.cfc" that I got from http://amazonsig.riaforge.org/index.cfm?event=action.download:

```
<cfcomponent hint="Amazon Product Advertising API Signature Generator">

    <cffunction name="signRequest" returntype="string" output="false"
        hint="Sign a request">

        <cfargument name="request" required="yes" type="string">
        <cfargument name="secretKey" required="yes" type="string">

        <!--- "Local" variable scope --->
        <cfset var lc = structnew()>

        <!--- Extract the URL part of the request and strip the protocol --->
        <cfset lc.requesturl = listfirst(arguments.request, "?")>
        <cfset lc.requesturl = replacenocase(lc.requesturl, "http://", "")>

        <!--- Split into host and path --->
        <cfset lc.host = listfirst(lc.requesturl, "/")>
        <cfset lc.path = right(lc.requesturl, len(lc.requesturl) - len(lc.host))>

        <!--- Process the query string parameters into a structure --->
        <cfset lc.querystring = listlast(arguments.request, "?")>
        <cfset lc.strParams = structnew()>
        <cfloop list="#lc.querystring#" index="i" delimiters="&">
            <cfset lc.strParams[listfirst(i, "=")] = urldecode(listlast(i, "="))>
        </cfloop>

        <!--- Add the timestamp --->
        <cfif not StructKeyExists(lc.strParams, "Timestamp")>
            <cfset lc.utcdate = dateconvert("local2Utc", now())>
            <cfset lc.timestamp = dateformat(lc.utcdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd') & "T" & timeformat(lc.utcdate, 'HH:mm:ss') & "Z">
            <cfset lc.strParams["Timestamp"] = lc.timestamp>
        </cfif>

        <!--- Sort the parameters --->
        <cfset lc.keys = listsort(structkeylist(lc.strParams), "text")>

        <!--- Generate a new query string including timestamp, with parameters in the correct order, encoding as we go --->
        <cfset lc.qs = "">
        <cfloop list="#lc.keys#" index="i">
            <cfset lc.qs = lc.qs & rfc3986EncodedFormat(i) & "=" & rfc3986EncodedFormat(lc.strParams[i]) & "&">
        </cfloop>

        <!--- Strip off the last & --->
        <cfset lc.qs = left(lc.qs, len(lc.qs)-1)>

        <!--- Build the string to sign --->
        <cfset lc.stringToSign = "GET" & chr(10)>
        <cfset lc.stringToSign = lc.stringToSign & lc.host & chr(10)>
        <cfset lc.stringToSign = lc.stringToSign & lc.path & chr(10)>
        <cfset lc.stringToSign = lc.stringToSign & lc.qs>

        <!--- Create the signature --->
        <cfset lc.binaryMsg = JavaCast("string",lc.stringToSign).getBytes("iso-8859-1")>
        <cfset lc.binaryKey = JavaCast("string",arguments.secretKey).getBytes("iso-8859-1")>
        <cfset lc.key = createObject("java","javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec")>
        <cfset lc.key.init(lc.binaryKey,"HmacSHA256")>
        <cfset lc.hmac = createObject("java","javax.crypto.Mac")>
        <cfset lc.hmac = lc.hmac.getInstance("HmacSHA256")>
        <cfset lc.hmac.init(lc.key)>
        <cfset lc.hmac.update(lc.binaryMsg)>
        <cfset lc.signature = lc.hmac.doFinal()>

        <!--- Return the new request URL --->
        <cfreturn "http://" & lc.host & lc.path & "?" & lc.qs & "&Signature=" & urlencodedformat(tobase64(lc.signature))>

    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="rfc3986EncodedFormat" returntype="string" output="false"
        hint="Perform some character encoding">
        <cfargument name="text" required="yes" type="string">
        <!--- "Local" variable scope --->
        <cfset var lc = structnew()>
        <cfset lc.objNet = createObject("java","java.net.URLEncoder")>
        <cfset lc.encodedText = lc.objNet.encode(arguments.text, 'utf-8').replace("+", "%20").replace("*", "%2A").replace("%7E", "~")>
        <cfreturn lc.encodedText>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

This is my cfm file "amazonsig.cfm"

```
<cfset requrl = "http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Operation=ItemSearch&AWSAccessKeyId=aaaa&AssociateTag=aaaaa&SearchIndex=Books&Keywords=Harry&ResponseGroup=Images,ItemAttributes,Offers">

<cfset amazonsig = createObject("component", "amazonsig")>
<cfset abc = amazonsig.signrequest(requrl,"aaa")>


<cfhttp url="#abc#" method="GET" result="response"  resolveurl="yes">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" >
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/json" >

</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#response#">
```

Note: the signature URL is correct because I hit directly in the browser and the response return correctly, but in <cfhttp> it is giving error.

[image]

Comment: The question is unclear. Signatures  *very* delicate. It is impossible to say why you are getting an invalid signature error without more information. Which API? What signature version is required? What is the exact code causing the error (omit any "secret" values of course)? What is the exact error message and code?

Comment: @Leigh First of all I tried a short cut approach. I got php code from amazon scratch pad sample for "itemsearch" api http://webservices.amazon.com/scratchpad/index.html
and then put the generated signature in <cfhttp> tag
in php it is working like a charm but the same signature is not working in coldfusion. It should work .

Comment: You still did not answer the questions above, or [on your other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786964/aws-signature-is-not-validating-in-amazon-api). Unfortunately, without more information all anyone can do is guess at this point. Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Leigh I have provided each and every detail.What you say now???

Comment: @Leigh waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it I was using coldfusion 11 with jdk 1.7 but when i run the code on coldfusion 10 with jdk 1.8 it successfully run.

Comment: Which is exactly what @P-Mascari told you in their answer - _latest version of Java_.  You may want to accept that answer for this question.

Comment: @Miguel-F no my fried this is not. I want to run the code on my current version. This is not a solution. I want to make it work on coldfusion 11 and jdk 1.7.

Comment: But the issue is that jdk 1.7 does not support it. It's not a ColdFusion issue, it is a JRE issue.  And support for Java 1.7 ended like two years ago and ColdFusion 10 support ends this month.  You need to update. There is a reason that Amazon supports only the latest security standards.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're running ColdFusion with the latest version of Java.  Many CF installs are using older JVMs which do not support the updated security features being used by many web services.

Here is a [blog post](http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/how-to-change-upgrade-jdk-version-of-coldfusion-server) with instructions for updating Java for ColdFusion.

Comment: @P Mascari I am using CF 11 with jdk 1.8